# I need a cooling pad for Macbook Pro (non-unibody)

Tags: macbook, cooling, cooling-pad

I am finding that my MBP (non-unibody) is running pretty hot and I believe it is starting to affect my battery's health.

Can the community personally recommend some cooling pads either battery or usb powered. Some of the criteria I am looking for in a cooling pad

- light weight/ portable
- won't scratch the bottom of the MBP
- 4+ fans
- quiet
- affordable

PS. I know about smcFanControl, I use it, but still not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently bought this cooling pad: [Targus Lap Chill Mat - AWE55US](http://www.targus.com/US/product_details.aspx?sku=AWE55US)

It is also comes highly rated at [cnet](http://reviews.cnet.com/docks-stands/targus-awe55us-lap-chill/4505-19213_7-33772538.html?tag=mncol;lst)

> **THE GOOD**: Subtle, mod design; quiet cooling; nice ergonomic tilt.
>
> **THE BAD**: Rubber stoppers can pull out easily.
>
> **THE BOTTOM LINE**: The Targus Lap Chill Mat is among the least-ugly laptop fan stands we've seen, helping it rise above the generic-looking competition.

Comment: i'll go an find one this weekend to try ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of your MBP - 13", 15", 17"?

I have a Targus AWE41US for my MBP 17".  It was pretty nice, but eventually (~6 months of use) its power receptacle loosened.  This means that you sometimes have to hold the plug in place if you want it to run!

However, it does work quite well aside from this - it cools the thing substantially and is not too unwieldy.  If you get one, make sure to get something to keep the laptop from sliding around (like velcro fasteners or [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008LDHV) non-slip pad that I use).